# VS 2003 fails to regsvr32 during post build. No issues from command prompt

Tags: c++

Regsvr32 fails as a post build event for a DLL project.

Post Build Event:
regsvr32 /s /c "$(TargetPath)" (also tried without quotes).

Removing the /s results in the error message
LoadLibrary("...") failed - The specified module could not be found.

If I run regsvr32 from command prompt the result is successful. If I copy and run or even directly run the "BAT000019.bat" file I get the resulting message "DllRegisterServer in ...dll succeeded." I have loaded the DLL in Dependency Walker and found no issues. This has worked in the past, but suddenly started having issues. I have about 50 projects which have the same post build event, only about 3 have this issue. The DLL file does exist at the time the bat file is generated (maybe it's in use???).

I don't see any issues with the generated bat file:

```
@echo off
regsvr32 /c "C:\ ... .dll"
if error level 1 goto VCReportError
goto VCEnd
:VCReportError
echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing registration"
exit 1
:VCEnd
```

Other information:
OS: Windows XP SP3.
IDE: VS 2003 Pro (up to date).
Language: C++

I could just remove the post build event, but would rather keep it for some of our newer program debuggers.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Other things I've tried:
Relative path to DLL in post build event. (fails)
Absolute path to DLL in post build event. (fails)
With an without quotes (nothing in the absolute path contains a space). (fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your project isn't made by just one DLL, maybe the DLL you're building depends on **other libraries** (check with DependencyWalker andverify if `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress` too) but they're not there for the post-build event of the dll.

If you run from the command prompt in the output directory there is everything your dll needs so it can be registered.

For what I know you can't set a post-build event for the solution so please check your project dependencies/build order). I assume you're not trying to register a dll alone in its output directory without its dependencies (the path in the batch should match `$(TargetPath)`)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. All of the dependencies exist in a predetermined path that has been added to the System Path environmental variable. This includes all msvc*70.dll and debug dll and any other re-distributional files.

Comment: It's a little bit tricky but: write a small program with a single parameter (full path), call it instead of regsrv32 in the post-build event, log what's going on (or attach in debug).

Comment: Created a stat application that takes a file as the command line parameter. I called my exe with $(TargetPath) as the parameter and got a successful hit on my dll existing with the correct file size and file permissions.

Great idea, but not seeing any useful information from my result.

Another note: $(TargetPath) is 68 characters.

Comment: Updated the stat app to call regsvr32.exe if the file exists. Running that stat app from visual studio with the absolute path to the DLL I want to register, and everything works perfectly. From the DLL project calling my stat app as a post build event. The file is found but it fails to regsvr32 with the same error as above. Very strange.

Comment: Try to load your dll with LoadLibrary from the "fake" app to check if it can be loaded (eventually try GetProcAddress for DllRegister)

Comment: LoadLibrary is successful. I can also run the DLL through our test application which allows us to call the various functions. No issues there. I may have neglected to day this is a COM object. Everything seems to work except for registering from a post build event. Maybe I should just wait and see if VS2010 has the same issue since we're migrating to that version eventually.

Comment: Finally figured this out. One of the DLLs being loaded needed to be added as a "DelayLoadDLLs" setting in the project settings.

Interesting that command prompt could figure it out, but Visual Studio could not.

Comment: I guess the devenv can't understand what you "delay" load so it can't use them to order dependencies.